# Error in cor(y): allocMatrix: too many elements specified

Tags: r, correlation

```
x <- read.table('file_name',header=TRUE, row.names=1)
y <- t(x)
y <- data.frame(y)
row.names(y) <- names(x)
names(y) <- row.names(x)
library(corrplot)
corr <- cor(y) 
par(ask = TRUE)
corrplot(corr, order = "hclust")
```

I'm trying use corrplot on my dataset. The original dataset has 25000 rows and 100 columns. I transposed to 25000 columns and 100 rows and finally applied corrplot. And failed!
If any help would be appreciated. [note:1st column is and first row are names and others are values (like -0.9 or 2.5 or 14449.45 etc.)]

Comment: in its present form the question is unanswerable, since it is not known what failed. One advice I can give is to reduce your data set and try again. Also look for NA values.

Comment: Is there a word missing in the note at the end? "1st column is ... and first row are names"

Comment: Why did you transpose? What are the rows/columns representing? How many pairwise correlations are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

The "allocMatrix: too many elements specified" error is thrown in on line 170 of `R/src/main/array.c` when nrow x ncol is greater than `INT_MAX` (+2,147,483,647).  `INT_MAX` is defined in the C standard library file "limits.h" and it is the same in the 32-bit and 64-bit toolchain used to build R, so no amount of RAM on a current 64-bit R build will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you don't have enough memory.  The correlation matrix for 25,000 columns will be 25,000 x 25000 which is about 4 gig. `(25000 ^ 2 * 8 ) / 1024 ^ 3)`

Comment: Since the error states `too many elements specified`, rather than `cannot allocate vector`, it seems that its an address space issue rather than a memory issue (though this would follow). This message kicks in if you attempt to allocate more than $2^31-1$ elements. While this doesn't seem to be the case here, there may be more elements in use than specified in the question above.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Comment: I'm running on 4gb RAM MacBook. Anyways thanx for the comments.